# Convert a column of WrappedArrays in Scala to a column of Vector[Double]

Tags: arrays, scala, vector

I have a dataframe in Scala with 3 observations. One of the columns contains wrapped arrays, such that when I write:

```
 df.select("column").collect()
```

I'll get back

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]= Array([WrappedArray(0.8, 0.5, 0.6)],[WrappedArray(0.6, 0.55, 0.7)], [WrappedArray(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)])
```

Is there a function to convert the wrapped arrays to vectors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
val vectorUDF = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf((array: Array[Double]) => {
Vectors.dense(array)
    })
df.withColumn("vector", vectorUDF(df.select("column"))).drop("column")
```

`Vectors.dense()` allows you to convert the array[Double] into vector value

Please check the import if you are using `ml` library or `mllib` one.

Hope This work